# Does that code creating new selector?

Tags: jquery

Here is the code:

```
$( "#myDiv a" ).attr( "href", "newDestination.html" );
```

Here we creating new selector a in div block and than add attr href?Or we should already have a for adding new attr to him?

Comment: Don't confuse the terms `selector` and `element`.  A `selector` *selects* an *existing* `element` - if it's not there, it doesn't select anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Answer is No.

**Explanation:**

```
$( "#myDiv a" ).attr( "href", "newDestination.html" );
```

In the above code you are just changing the `href` of already existing `a` tag which is inside `div` with `id` = `myDiv`

Answer (score 1):

JQuery function that selects elements by this selector `$( "#myDiv a" )` will yield empty set as there is no such element in the DOM at the time this function is invoked. Therefore **it will not add new anchor** tag.

What you want to do can be obtained by the following:

```
$("#myDiv").append("<a href='newDestination.html'></a>" );
```